# At/In highest quality?

Tags: prepositions

I'm currently stuck on the right preposition followed by "highest quality" as in:

"I make sure the posters are printable *at/in their highest quality*."

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying "I assure the posters can be printed at high quality." or "I do print the posters at highest quality." In the first you're auditing the poster data or press master for flaws, resolution issues, color gamut, etc. In the second you're running the printer.

Comment: I think you may be aiming for "I make sure that the posters we print are of the highest quality."

Comment: Is the 'highest quality' here the highest imaginable quality, or are we talking about something like a setting on a printer?

Answer (score 1):

Which preposition you use for the phrase "highest quality" definitely depends on the context. In your poster example, I would go with "in" because "at" implies some sort of location, real or metaphorical, as in "The fruit is at its highest quality directly after it is picked." Although this sentence is a bit strange, you absolutely could not use "in".

But whichever preposition you use, the sentence about the posters still sounds awkward, so you might want to change the sentence around entirely.

"I make sure the posters are printable..." There are lots of different ways to finish this sentence with the general meaning you are going for.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I might go for "I make sure that the posters we print are of the highest quality." instead.
However, the reason I used the word "printable" was that I wanted to refer "quality" to the sense of clarity(e.g. right performance of pixels and size etc, so the output looks perfectly fit). If I used the preferred statement above, it seems to me that the "quality" refers to a general aesthetic sense instead. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks:)!